# Python Copy Command (shutil?)

Tags: python, copying, shutil, file-copying

I have a rPi running raspbmc and I created autoexec.py which runs on startup.  Inside autoexec.py, I put the following code:

```
import os
import shutil

shutil.copyfile(/mnt/usb/scripts/guisettings.xml, /home/pi/.xbmc/userdata/guisettings.xml)
```

However, I am getting an error every time I attempt to run this script.  I have checked the log files and it only shows the following:

```
-->Python callback/script returned the following error<--
- NOTE: IGNORING THIS CAN LEAD TO MEMORY LEAKS!
Error Type: <type 'exceptions.SyntaxError'>
Error Contents: ('invalid syntax', ('autoexec.py', 4, 17, 'shutil.copyfile(/mnt/usb/scripts/guisettings.xml, /home/pi$
SyntaxError: ('invalid syntax', ('autoexec.py', 4, 17, 'shutil.copyfile(/mnt/usb/scripts/guisettings.xml, /home/pi/.x$
-->End of Python script error report<--
```

What am I doing wrong here?  I have been attempting this for the past hour.

Comment: one thing I can think of is you need to put the source and destination in quotes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to quote literal strings in Python:

```
shutil.copyfile('/mnt/usb/scripts/guisettings.xml', 
                '/home/pi/.xbmc/userdata/guisettings.xml')
```